# .getElementsByTagName not disabling buttons created in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom, button

I am trying to disable buttons that were created in JavaScript...

```
var upButton = document.createElement('button');
var  downButton= document.createElement('button');
var deleteButton = document.createElement('button');
```

Here is where I select all the buttons but its not working...

```
function play() {
  var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
  buttons.disabled = true;
  buttons.style.backgroundColor = "#DADAD9";
}
```

The function is getting called and works but disabling does not.
Can anyone help me out? Thanks!

Comment: buttons is an array of elements, so won't have the `disabled` property.

Comment: you should debug your problems with breakpoints, or `console.log`s in future to be able to solve it yourself.

Comment: @judgeja thanks, I looped through them and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

`getElementsByTagName` returns an array, you need to loop over the results.

```
function play() {
    var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");

    for (i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
        buttons[i].disabled = true;
        buttons[i].style.backgroundColor = "#DADAD9";
    }
}
```

Comment: the solution works, but, the explanation isn't exactly correct.